# How to use JohnSnowLabs NLP Spell correction module NorvigSweetingModel?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nlp, apache-spark-ml, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I was going through the JohnSnowLabs SpellChecker [here](https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/components.html).

I found the `Norvig`'s algorithm implementation there, and the example section has just the following two lines:

```
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotator.NorvigSweetingModel
NorvigSweetingModel.pretrained()
```

How can I apply this pretrained model on my dataframe (`df`)below for spell correcting the "`names`" column?

```
+----------------+---+------------+
|           names|age|       color|
+----------------+---+------------+
|      [abc, cde]| 19|    red, abc|
|[eefg, efa, efb]|192|efg, efz efz|
+----------------+---+------------+
```

I have tried to do it as follows:

```
val schk = NorvigSweetingModel.pretrained().setInputCols("names").setOutputCol("Corrected")

val cdf = schk.transform(df)
```

But the above code gave me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Wrong or missing inputCols annotators in SPELL_a1f11bacb851. Received inputCols: names. Make sure such columns have following annotator types: token
  at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
  at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.AnnotatorModel.transform(AnnotatorModel.scala:51)
  ... 49 elided
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spark-nlp` are designed to be used in its own specific pipelines and input columns for different transformers have to include special metadata.

The exception already tells you that input to the `NorvigSweetingModel` should be tokenized:

> Make sure such columns have following annotator types: token

If I am not mistaken,  at minimum you'll have assemble documents and tokenized here.

```
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.DocumentAssembler
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotator.NorvigSweetingModel
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.Tokenizer
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline

val df = Seq(Seq("abc", "cde"), Seq("eefg", "efa", "efb")).toDF("names")

val nlpPipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(
  new DocumentAssembler().setInputCol("names").setOutputCol("document"),
  new Tokenizer().setInputCols("document").setOutputCol("tokens"),
  NorvigSweetingModel.pretrained().setInputCols("tokens").setOutputCol("corrected")
))
```

A `Pipeline` like this, can be applied on your data with small adjustment - input data has to be `string` not `array<string>`*:

```
val result = df
  .transform(_.withColumn("names", concat_ws(" ", $"names")))
  .transform(df => nlpPipeline.fit(df).transform(df))
result.show()
```

```
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|       names|            document|              tokens|           corrected|
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     abc cde|[[document, 0, 6,...|[[token, 0, 2, ab...|[[token, 0, 2, ab...|
|eefg efa efb|[[document, 0, 11...|[[token, 0, 3, ee...|[[token, 0, 3, ee...|
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

If you want an output that can be exported you should extend your `Pipeline` with `Finisher`.

```
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.Finisher

new Finisher().setInputCols("corrected").transform(result).show
```

```
 +------------+------------------+
 |       names|finished_corrected|
 +------------+------------------+
 |     abc cde|        [abc, cde]|
 |eefg efa efb|  [eefg, efa, efb]|
 +------------+------------------+
```

---

* According to [the docs](https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/components.html) `DocumentAssembler`

> can read either a String column or an Array[String]

but it doesn't look like it works in practice in 1.7.3:

```
df.transform(df => nlpPipeline.fit(df).transform(df)).show()
```

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(names)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`names`' is of array<string> type.;;
'Project [names#62, UDF(names#62) AS document#343]
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Project [value#60 AS names#62]
         +- LocalRelation [value#60]
```

Comment: How to get the spell corrected values. Values under "corrected" comes as `[[token, 0, 3, eefg, [sentence -> 1]], [token, 5, 7, efa, [sentence -> 1]], [token, 9, 11, efb, [sentence -> 1]]]`

Comment: Does each of this list items, like [sentence ->1], have any standard structure/meaning?

Comment: @user3243499 _How to get the spell corrected values_ - Please check the `Finisher` part.

Comment: _Does each of this list items, like [sentence ->1], have any standard structure/meaning?_ - it is metadata. It is `map<string,string>` so structure is not fixed, but in this case it contains information about the sentence form the document.